# PHP: What line of this code does the actual file uploading?

Tags: php, file-upload

I´m reading [this php book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329166), and I´m following along all exercises.

But this one I don´t get. It´s an example of an HTML form that allows the user (with proper permissions) to upload a file.

I´ve looked for allphp functions mentioned in the example, but can´t understand where the file is actually uploaded.

The books says that should be here, inside the /uploads directory:

```
  // put the file where we'd like it
  $upfile = '/uploads/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
```

**But can´t understand, because it´s just assigning a value to a variable... there´s no "upload" function in that line... is it?**

### HTML FORM:

```
<h1>Upload new news files</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method=post>
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
  Upload this file: <input name="userfile" type="file">
  <input type="submit" value="Send File">
</form>
```

### PHP FILE:

```
<body>
<h1>Uploading file...</h1>
<?php

//Check to see if an error code was generated on the upload attempt
  if ($_FILES['userfile']['error'] > 0)
  {
    echo 'Problem: ';
    switch ($_FILES['userfile']['error'])
    {
      case 1:   echo 'File exceeded upload_max_filesize';
                break;
      case 2:   echo 'File exceeded max_file_size';
                break;
      case 3:   echo 'File only partially uploaded';
                break;
      case 4:   echo 'No file uploaded';
                break;
      case 6:   echo 'Cannot upload file: No temp directory specified.';
                break;
      case 7:   echo 'Upload failed: Cannot write to disk.';
                break;
    }
    exit;
  }

  // Does the file have the right MIME type?
  if ($_FILES['userfile']['type'] != 'text/plain')
  {
    echo 'Problem: file is not plain text';
    exit;
  }

  // put the file where we'd like it
  $upfile = '/uploads/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];

  if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) 
  {
     if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $upfile))
     {
        echo 'Problem: Could not move file to destination directory';
        exit;
     }
  } 
  else 
  {
    echo 'Problem: Possible file upload attack. Filename: ';
    echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    exit;
  }


  echo 'File uploaded successfully<br><br>'; 

  // reformat the file contents
  $fp = fopen($upfile, 'r');
  $contents = fread ($fp, filesize ($upfile));
  fclose ($fp);

  $contents = strip_tags($contents);
  $fp = fopen($upfile, 'w');
  fwrite($fp, $contents);
  fclose($fp);

  // show what was uploaded
  echo 'Preview of uploaded file contents:<br><hr>';
  echo $contents;
  echo '<br><hr>';

?>
</body>
```

Comment: when the form is posted, php receives the file to a temp file location which is specified in `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`. Then `move_uploaded_file` moves it from the temp location to the location you want

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But shouldn´t I call move_uploaded_file? I mean I´m just checking if move_uploaded_file doesn´t work.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` is being called in the condition. It returns true or false depending on if it's successful or fails

Comment: Ohh, I see. So there´s no need for an explicit "else"... THANKS!

Comment: right. So it does it and returns true or false. Then then that return value is inverted with that `!`. So basically if the file fails to be moved from `move_uploaded_file` then it will return false. Now invert that with `!false` to make the condition true and you get that "problem" msg.

Comment: another way to write that would be `if (move_uploaded_file(..)) echo 'success!'; else echo 'failed!';`

Comment: Yes, and BTW, it would be better, more clear, that way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does the upload for you.

What you have to manage is move the uploaded file from temp folder to wherever you want it (you do that using the `move_uploaded_file` function).

The `if(!move_uploaded_file(...` conditions will try to move the file to the folder, and if it fails (basically because of permission issues) will execute the code in the `if`.

Note that your code is exploitable with XSS :

```
echo 'Problem: Possible file upload attack. Filename: ';
echo htmlentities($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
exit;
```

Also note that anyone could upload any php scripts with this and mess your server, NEVER use this script on a production environment.

Before moving your file you'll have to check it's mime type, its extension, and preferably move it somewhere it couldn't be interpreted by apache.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I should assume that the if with the "!move_uploaded_file" just assumes that if it´s not into that condition, it will go ahead and upload the file with the move_uploaded_file function? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the warning...!! (what kind of author use that kind of dangerous code in a book supposed to be for learning to write good code, anyway?)

Comment: Yes I'm surprised, your book sucks.

Comment: don't be so quick to judge the book. There are plenty of building blocks and principles to learn that aren't necessarily good by themselves in a production environment. e.g. chapter 1 database coding I would not dive into how to write better, secure stuff. i would teach the basic principles first and then go from there.  Any good book worth a damn does this sort of thing - and has a disclaimer about it somewhere.  The book has 119 reviews with 4.3/5 stars overall on amazon. don't be so quick to judge @Loïc

Comment: @CrayonViolent I believe that it is important to mention security before teaching people how to upload random files on their server.

Answer (score 1):

PHP receives the file when you submit the form. Assuming you have the `enctype` attribute in your `<form>` tag like below, the browser sends the file to the server to be handled by PHP.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

PHP receives the file from the browser and stores it in a temporary location as configured in your `php.ini`.

Then it's a case of validating the uploaded file and moving it to a new location using the `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` temporary name.

The `move_uploaded_file()` function is then used rather the copying the file or moving it using `copy()` or `rename()` because the function checks to ensure the file was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism, as a security measure.

Even if you do not write any code to handle the upload, it still occurs and the file is stored in the temporary directory ready for processing. So to summarise, the upload takes place automatically by PHP.